# How to get network packets from Ethernet card in ANSI C?

Tags: c, ethernet

I have to write some code to retrieve network packets from an Ethernet card in Windows using ANSI C.  Can anybody tell me where to get started?

Comment: Did you use a search engine or a book?

Comment: ANSI C doesn't specify how to do network interactions. What's the platform you're targeting?

Comment: Get libpcap: http://www.tcpdump.org/

Comment: ANSI C is 22 years old - why are you required to use such an ancient standard, *on Windows*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the PCAP library, there's a version for Windows [here](http://www.winpcap.org/)
 and a basic example [here](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut2.html)